# Facebook api email required

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am using the api (http) facebook some time now, but I detected a problem a few days ago ... There is people to withdraw permission email which then cause inconsistencies in the system.

**There is no possibility to stop the login process if you have no access to email?**

I was trying another solution. In the callback see if you have the email or not variable. The problem is that the user can not log in again because the facebook is already saved your preference not to allow email.

Comment: If they have denied/removed the ability to see email via the API then no, you cannot force the API to let you see it.

Comment: there is no possibility to stop the login process if you have no access to email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't stop the login process itself. After the Facebook login process, you can make a call to fetch their email from the Graph API and present an error message stating email is required. Consider permitting them to enter it into a form on your side at this point - maybe they don't want your app's emails going to the email address they use for Facebook.

Do note that many Facebook accounts have no email address at all, as it's possible to sign up with just a phone number. Rejecting these users is generally not the best idea for user experience.